# Development to Production Environment Help

Tags: environment, production, staging

I am in serious need of some suggestions on how to improve the way I am doing things right now.  I currently manage over 100 websites and they are all on a Dedicated Server, I just log on the FTP and make the necessary changes and upload it.. so I always work live.

I know that is a bad idea and I really want to find a good solution on how to use a development server and then push to production when ready, and keep everything up to date, etc.

I also have two more people on the team go in and occasionally make changes to websites, so this is something that would work for all of us so we are all on the same page and have the most up to date code.

I have been doing a ton of research on this but a lot of it confuses me and I can't find a clear answer on what would be best for me.  I have tried git before, and it works great but not sure how that would work with 100+ websites.

I'm not sure where to even start.. what would be the best option?  Are there any services out there that I could pay for to make the process easier?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I would do is create a local development copy of the websites. Stop messing with code on your production server!

Next I would put the sites into version control. You can use any of the open source tools available (Subversion, Git, etc.). Just get this done.

You can write a script to deploy each site to the production server or you can play it safe and use a diff tool to copy over the changes only.

Comment: Thanks.  So every site would have its own Repository?  Where do I make changes from, my localhost?  So make changes to my localhost and make sure everything is working and then update the files on git, and push it to the production server?

Comment: Having 100+ repositories might be a but much. You can make a single repository with 100+ projects in it. I am envisioning each website as a collection of source files each contained in a directory.

Comment: So let me ask a question, why not just take the git middle man out and just download a copy of the files to my localhost before making any changes, make my changes and test everything, and then upload it back to FTP?

Comment: Once you remove version control you lose the ability to backout changes selectively. Also, change history is gone. You wind up dealing with dealing with snapshots of a system. Without a staging area it is too easy to introduce bad code/errors into the system.

Comment: Oh okay, thank you!  Last question.. if I have 1 Repository with 100 folders for my clients.. when I am cloning and whatnot, wouldn't it clone all 100 folders.. since it is just 1 URL for that 1 repository.  How would that work?

Comment: What are you cloning? If you have a code base you can make changes locally and push them to the repository. For example, edit index.html for client A in directory ~/a-www. You test locally and are happy so you commit your change the version control. Next, get your source on the development server. This could be called a build. Test you changes in the development web server. If all goes well then you push that specific change to production. It's all controlled, revertable and nothing goes the production by accident.